# is there any way to reduce the Tags browse time in OPC UA client?... while connected OPC UA Server

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, opc-ua, opc

I have reduce and checked with **SamplingInterval and PublishingInterval**..values There is no impact.
can you suggest any way? Let me know.

Comment: SamplingInterval and PublishingInterval are for subscriptions (monitored items). They are not related to browsing. What do you mean by "Tag browse time"? Are you doing one Browse call, and that call takes a long time, or are you doing multiple calls and they in total take "long"?

Comment: I have configured bulk tags in Kep server. while browsing the folders in Address Space in client, to open the bulk tags present in that folder. It is taking more time for one browse call. What may be the issue?

Comment: If there is a huge number of tags (how many?), and the client is not doing something "stupid" (such as browsing in small chunks), there may be no help, because it can simply be the time the server needs to fulfill the request, plus time to transmit the data. If there is a way you actually do not need all the tags but can specify a narrow(er) filter, use it, to reduce the amount of data/tags. But, of course in some cases you really do need all the tags...

Answer (score 2):

As noted before, *SamplingInterval* and *PublishingInterval* will not affect the *Browse* service. That's why you don't see any improvement.

Browsing in OPC UA is quite expensive on both ends, but you can probably manage some optimization.

I do not know what technology (or SDK or language) you are using but here's a list of things you could investigate:

1. **Filter you Browse request**: for example, if you are only interested in objects and variables but not so much on types etc. you could apply a *nodeClassMask* to your Browse request (your SDK or stack should allow that). This will tremendously reduce the information going across for the response.
2. **Choose your browsing direction**: in the Browse request, you can specify the *browseDirection* flag to tell the server to follow certain types of references (forward, reverse, or both). In most cases forward is what you'd want if you are browsing for variables and objects. This will also speed up the request/response. You will see that parameter in the same specification and also in your SDK documentation.
3. **Pick a reference type to follow**: similarly to #2, you can select one specific reference type to use for your Browse (i.e. Organizes, HasComponent, HasTypeDefinition, etc.) to reduce payloads. This Browse request parameter is called referenceTypeId .

Details on things you can do with a Browse requests are in [this section of the OPC Specification](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/docs/Part4/5.8.2/#Table34).

To give you an idea, here's a snippet using the OPC UA .NET-Standard C# API to make a browse request with some of those parameters filtered:

```
session.Browse(
                null,
                null,
                ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder,
                0u,
                BrowseDirection.Forward, //forward only
                ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, //only hierarchical
                true,
                (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method,
                out continuationPoint,
                out references);
```

Hopefully this will help you bit. OPC UA can be cumbersome at times...